# fs2: Check for success of Seq(Task)

Tags: scala, task, scalaz, http4s, fs2

I have an asynchronous http4s client from which I get a collection of results, after running some requests. I want to check that this collection (a `Seq[Task[Response]]`) has finished for all `Task` objects, and that the `Response` objects are in a specific state.

If I were using `Future` instead of Task, I would do something like

```
val results: Seq[Future[Response]] = ...
Future.sequence(results).map(_.forall(_.customFunction.isSuccess))
```

Is there a way to achieve similar functionality using `fs2.Task` instead? In my limited understanding, I assume at some point I will have to call `unsafeRun`, which would block for each `Task` in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace `Future.sequence` with something like:

```
val results: Seq[Task[Response]] = ...
val sequence: Task[Seq[Response]] = results.foldLeft(Task.now(Seq.empty[Response])) {
  (x, t) => x.flatMap(s => t.map(r => s :+ r))
}
```

Then do the success checking the same way.